# get user information using Facebook custom login in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I'm trying to get user information using a custom facebook login with the Facebook SDK for iOS. I successfully log in the user but I don't know how to get access to the user information.
This is my login function:

```
func facebookLogin() {
    if (FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.Open || FBSession.activeSession().state == FBSessionState.OpenTokenExtended)
    {
        // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
        // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
        FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
    }
    else
    {
        // Open a session showing the user the login UI
        // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session

        FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email"], allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: {
            (session:FBSession!, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError!) in
            self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
        })
    }

}
```

Then when the session is open the function sessionStateChanged is called:

```
func sessionStateChanged(session:FBSession, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError?){
    if ((error) != nil){
        NSLog("Error")
        FBSession.activeSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation()
    }
    else{
        if (state == FBSessionState.Open){
            //I would like to get the user token or FBGraphUser here but i don't know how
        }

    }
    if (state == FBSessionState.Closed || state == FBSessionState.ClosedLoginFailed){
        NSLog("Session Clossed")
    }
    if (FBErrorUtility.shouldNotifyUserForError(error) == true){
        NSLog("Something went wrong")
    }
    else{
        if (FBErrorUtility.errorCategoryForError(error) == FBErrorCategory.UserCancelled){
            NSLog("User cancelled login")
        }
        else if (FBErrorUtility.errorCategoryForError(error) == FBErrorCategory.AuthenticationReopenSession){
            NSLog("Current session is no valid")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the exact same problem today! I'm not sure if this is the ideal way of doing things, but this is the workaround that my colleague showed me:

```
FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], allowLoginUI: false) { session, state, error in

let request = FBRequest(session: FBSession.activeSession(), graphPath: "/me")
request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

    println(result)
    let birthday = result.valueForKey("birthday") as String
    println("\(birthday)")
})

self.fbSessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
}
```

Please forgive the ugly code, I'm still very much experimenting with Swift. Hope it helps!

Comment: It's not working for me, could you write your view controller please?

Comment: What part isn't working? You'll obviously need to have `fbSessionStateChanged(...)` declared somewhere and your facebook app properly set up as described in the [Facebook developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#appid).

Comment: I have that function declared and my Facebook app properly set up, but when I execute your code my view controller does nothing, It just stay in the view and It's not redirecting me to the Facebook login page or giving me any information of user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

1. Add FBLoginViewDelegate to the class
2. Declare this

   ```
   @IBOutlet var fbLoginView : FBLoginView!
   ```
3. Connect this var (fbLoginView) with a new view in your storyboard. This new view can be hidden so it wont has any effect but helping you to track the information
4. In your viewDidLoad

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       //facebook login
       self.fbLoginView.delegate = self
       self.fbLoginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
   }
   ```
5. And add this function

   ```
   func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(LoginView : FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser){
       println("User name: \(user.name)")
       //THE USER WAS LOGGED
   }
   ```
6. When the user is authenticated by facebook, returns to loginViewFetchedUserInfo method automatically by using the FBLoginViewDelegate and you can get the information with the "user" variable

Comment: This is not for custom login